# How to build anonymous types, taking the name from a variable?

Tags: c#, json, anonymous-types

I want create a customized JSON string like this:

```
{"service1":"hello"}
```

*( I simplified the example. In reality the required JSON is more complex.
But to explain the problem, this example is fine )*

My problem is that the service name "service1" is contained in a variable
This is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public static string CreateCustomJSON(string serviceName, object value)
    {
        var v = new { serviceName = value };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        return json;
    }

CreateCustomJSON("service1", "hello");
CreateCustomJSON("service2", "John");
CreateCustomJSON("service3", 13);
```

I got this result:

```
{"serviceName":"hello"}
{"serviceName":"John"}
{"serviceName":13}
```

because i do not know how to use Anonymous Types properly

The error is in this line:

```
var v = new { serviceName = value };
```

Or maybe there is another way to follow,
to build a customized json string

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you *want* an anonymous type at all? Why not just create a class and make it easier for users of your code to understand what it does and what members it has?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary<string,string>` for this. Json object are dictionaries after all. [Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmggVH)

```
public static string CreateCustomJSON(string serviceName, string value)
{
    var v = new Dictionary<string,string> {{serviceName, value}};
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    return json;
}

public static void Main()
{
    CreateCustomJSON("service1", "hello");
    CreateCustomJSON("service2", "John");
}
```

output:

```
{"service1":"hello"}
{"service2":"John"}
```

Comment: Good answer. I'm frustrated as I was first and you got the upvotes. Anyway: no damage done, the OP got the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a string to return that ...

```
public static string CreateCustomJSON(string serviceName, string value)
{
    var json = $"{{ \"{serviceName}\":\"{ value}\" }}";
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    return json;
}
```

Unless the required JSON is more complex then you can use reflection

Comment: This is not a bad idea in fact.

Comment: fixed the missing quotations, still if I didn't use the $ you'll have too many " like this: "{ \""+serviceName+"\":\""+value+"\" }"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary

```
var x = new Dictionary<string,string>();

x.Add ("service1", "val1");
```

---

### Edit - full example

```
    public static string CreateCustomJSON(string serviceName, string value)
    {
        var x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        x.Add(serviceName, value);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CreateCustomJSON("service1", "hello"));
        Console.WriteLine(CreateCustomJSON("service2", "John"));
    }
```

Retult:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use ExpandoObject. Try this if fits your needs

```
public static void AddPropertyToObject(ExpandoObject o, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> d = o as IDictionary<string, object>;

    if (d == null) return;

    if (!d.ContainsKey(propertyName))
    {
                d.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
            }
            else
            {
                d[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            }
        }
```

And then

```
dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
AddPropertyToObject(eo, "test", "fsdf");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eo);
```